# can i convert a psd into a storyboard or an uiViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, psd

I am trying to do an iPhone application and someone send me some psds for the design. I have done a big part of my project but i arrive in some complex view wich will take me ages to develop correctly.

I would like to know if there is any way to convert the psd file into a `NIB`, `storyboard`, or `UIViewController` to win some time?

Comment: Why will it take you ages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. That sounds like it would literally have to be magic to work.

The closest thing I can suggest is using PaintCode (http://www.paintcodeapp.com/). It will generate Objective-C code using design files (it can import PSD files). That said, I have very limited experience with it and do not know the limitations of the software. Definitely worth a shot though.

Comment: +1 for "literally have to be magic." A PSD doesn't even come close to containing the necessary information to make an app workable.

Comment: paintCode looks interesting for the buttons and smalls design but what bother me the most it's how to developp fast the complex view controller. for exemple if i analyse one of the psd "page", i should developp a "page" with 2 different tableVIew (deferent style) wich customs cells to looks more like a grid,  and some other information that i display out of the tables view. Nothing impossible and it looks awsome but it's something wich is not so important on my project. if i don't find any magic power to use this PSD, i would rather change the design. thanks for the answers!

Comment: For what it's worth, what you're describing would be best made with a UICollectionView rather than a UITableView. That said, work is work. There is only so much automation that can be done for you with tools like this. There is no way a program would be able to take a complex layout and make it into a working app, it is just not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Its now 2016, try Export Kit: http://exportkit.com/lightning-storm-cc, there is no magic only speed.  Works with PSD and AI, it will convert your design to XCode with Storyboard and SWift - also has Android support if you need that as well.

PSD to iOS: http://exportkit.com/learn/how-to/export-your-psd/psd-to-ios-storyboard-ui-with-xcode-and-swift